# Comparison of KS test and MWW test

Tags: hypothesis-testing, t-test, wilcoxon-mann-whitney-test, kolmogorov-smirnov-test

I want to compare two data samples which come from continuous distributions. However, the data is highly skewed and t-test is obviously not a choice. As an alternative, I wanted to use the MWW test for locational shift, but one of the assumptions is that the distributions of the groups should be similar, but in my case one group has a much longer tail than the other.

My last choice was the KS test used to compare arbitrary distributions. However, after running the test, the result was not significant, and so the conclusion is that there isn't enough evidence that the distributions of the two groups differ significantly.

What troubles me is that I argued not to use MWW because the distributions differ, but KS said they don't differ significantly. Can somebody explain if my reasoning is valid, or is there something I forgot to consider?

Edit: this is how the distributions look like
[image: Boxplots of the groups]

[image: ECDFs of the groups]

Comment: "but one of the assumptions is that the distributions of the groups should be similar" - where's that from? Not really. (Although there are some specific situations in which WMW can be misleading.) How many observations do you have in your two groups? Can you show the distributions? Of course we can't know otherwise how reliable your "much longer tail" assessment is.

Comment: "What troubles me is that I argued not to use MWW because the distributions differ, but KS said they don't differ significantly. " Yeah, that should trouble you. Maybe your intuition for spotting differences is wrong.

Comment: Note that WMW will reject if one distribution produces systematically bigger values than the other, whereas KS looks for any kind of difference, not necessarily "one generally bigger than the other". Depending on what exactly your data mean and what your aim is, one of these may be more appropriate than the other.

Comment: @ChristianHennig, I have added the example of the distributions of the groups, both groups have over 100 observations. The assumption of the similarity of distributions was my conclusion since MWW tests the locational shift, and since one group is more right skewed than the other (and also more spread), they can't just differ in the shift.

Comment: Looking at the boxplots, assuming that the numbers of observations in both groups are very similar, I find it rather astonishing that KS doesn't give you a significant result there. The first thing I'd do is check that it was done correctly.

Comment: MWW does not test "locational shift", rather MWW tests whether one distribution is stochastically larger than the other, regardless of their shapes. Locational shift is just one special case of this. I know that it is claimed in some places that MWW tests for "shift", but this is rather misleading.

Comment: However, MWW may do what you need here anyway, in which case there's not much reason to even bother with KS.

Comment: @ChristianHennig, groups have just over 100 and 200 observations, resp., and KS gives a p-value of 0.06888 :S
When it comes to MWW, can you give some source where MWW is applied to groups with different shapes?

Comment: This one discusses the issue in depth: https://projecteuclid.org/journals/statistics-surveys/volume-4/issue-none/Wilcoxon-Mann-Whitney-or-t-test-On-assumptions-for-hypothesis/10.1214/09-SS051.full

Comment: The general issues are vital  -- and so is knowing and seeing enough about the data to advise on analysis. Specifically the data are explained in a comment to be times, so presumably no zeros are present. Have you tried analysing on logarithmic or reciprocal scale? The reciprocal of time is a speed, often a natural measure. It may be an illusion but the distribution plots seem to indicate similar patterns for low values and different patterns for high values. Here, as often, the box plots are not much help really, but the distribution plots are more helpful (although I prefer quantile plots).

Comment: I really like [this answer](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/292026/237901) by @gung to the question: Can the Wilcoxon rank sum test give a different result to the Kolmogorov-Smirnov test result? The short answer is: yes, they can.

Answer (score 2):

[I apologize in advance for the tone of exasperation that comes into what I write below when the question suddenly shifts from appearing to ask for advice about what test to do to revealing that you already tested the hypothesis. I'll leave it as is, but be prepared for that.]

> I want to compare two data samples which come from continuous distributions.

This is too vague a statement to start choosing a test from. You need to more clearly express what the research question is/what you need to find out/what you're doing this for.

> However, the data is highly skewed and t-test is obviously not a choice.

It seems like the responses for the two groups are strictly non-negative quantities.

What are the data measuring? What values are possible and impossible for the variable?

Why did you consider a t-test in the first place? Your initial sentence (you simply expressed a wish to compare two distributions) gives no hint that a t-test would be a suitable choice; it's specifically about comparing means under a set of conditions.

> As an alternative, I wanted to use the MWW test for locational shift, but one of the assumptions is that the distributions of the groups should be similar, but in my case one group has a much longer tail than the other.

A location shift alternative usually doesn't make sense with a non-negative variable. I'd say more if I knew more about the variable, but you should probably consider whether a different sort of alternative makes sense (e.g. a scale-shift alternative often makes sense in such cases).

If you considered a t-test, you were apparently interested in comparing means; that's still possible with a scale-shift, given any of a large class of suitable models (or can be done nonparametrically).

If you don't insist on restricting yourself to a location-shift alternative, the WMW would be fine as long as it corresponds to your alternative of interest.

> My last choice was the KS test used to compare arbitrary distributions.

Given your earlier statement that you sought a location shift alternative, that makes no sense -- you definitely would not be getting a *pure* location-shift alternative with this test (it rejects other things as well). If you want a "tends to be bigger" alternative, WMW would do that. If you want a scale shift alternative (which I expect will make a lot of sense once you explain what you're measuring), then you could easily go back to a comparison of means.

> However, after running the test,

Then it seems you're done in any case, there's nothing more to be done now.

If you did a test already, you don't get to backpedal and choose a different test because the one you did was not powerful enough to reject. To  choose to do another test in that circumstance would seem to be p hacking.

> What troubles me is that I argued not to use MWW because the distributions differ,

Your problem was insisting on a location shift alternative (which is the only reason you'd need them to be the same shape under the alternative), an added requirement (above what the WMW needs) that you were nonetheless happy to abandon when moving to the KS test instead.

This inconsistency (not using WMW because it didn't appear to satisfy a condition you immediately abandoned anyway) seems strange to say the least.

> Can somebody explain if my reasoning is valid, or is there something I forgot to consider?

When looking to do a test (assuming a test actually answers the question of interest):

1. First figure out what sort of alternatives (a) make sense to consider given your variable, and (b) that would be of interest.

   (Why insist on a location shift alternative? Why then abandon it so readily?)
2. Then choose a suitable distributional model (or choose to avoid any specific distributional model). On that basis, choose a suitable test.
3. Don't use more than one test.

Additional comment: As a general rule, using the specific data set (e.g. via your boxplot) to inform your test choice may be problematic, as choosing the specific hypothesis on the basis of the exact same sample values you want to test it on impacts the properties of the test. If you can inform yourself about how the variable should behave (at least under H0) without having to do that, so much the better.

Comment: The data show time in minutes (e.g. 1.5 is 1 min and 30 sec) for completing some task, and I wanted to see if the time needed differs between the two groups of people in the sample. Does one group differ significantly from the other? I guess this also sounds vague by your standards. I know that KS is used to compare distributions, and judging from your comment, it shouldn't be considered as an alternative to testing means or medians (to which I agree).

Since none of the tests I considered (and with which I'm familiar with) are not suitable, can you suggest some which would make sense?

Comment: "you definitely would not be getting a location-shift alternative with this (KS) test."  The two-sample KS-test tests whether distributions are equal against any alternative, including location shift. It may have worse power for that than WMW or t, but I don't agree with "definitely would not get".

Comment: @ChristianHennig The trouble I see is that KS can reject for all kinds of reasons, so there is little reason to think a rejection indicates a location shift when the culprit just as easily could be unequal scale.

Comment: @Dave I think we all agree that KS isn't a good choice if it is of interest whether one distribution tends to produce larger values than the other. My comment was just technical; KS *will* reject in case there is location shift and the sample is big enough for having enough power (even though the power is in this case quite certainly weaker than WMW).